# Can't schedule a VBScript in scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a wsf file, which I will paste below, which I am trying to schedule in Windows Server Task Scheduler.

The wsf runs fine if I try to execute it manually, but the task scheduler won't run it.  As I watch, I can see the task status switch to "Running", and, after about 10 seconds (the hung task kill is set to 1 hour) switch back.  I see nothing running in the background (I don't know whether I should), and the script that it runs (telnetting to another server and executing a command) hasn't been executed.

I'm sure it's a stupid permissions issue, but after a couple of weeks of on and off googling and question asking, I can't figure it out.

Below is the script, in case anything it's doing helps.

```
<job>
<script language="VBScript">
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run ("Telnet")
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys("Open 172.16.8.9")
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys"csmmgr"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys("quality")
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys "@dsm nyf/vol=nyf/data=""100"" JOB{^}ZLEGDWPJ"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys "lo"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
oShell.sendkeys"^]"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys "q {Enter}"
</script>
</job>
```

--sw

Comment: Is "system administrator" different from a user with the System Admin privilege?

Answer (score 0):

On the Task Tab Set it to run as system administator. You have to save the password by pressing on **set password** button.